# SQL number of products

Tags: sql, count

I have two tabels :

```
--Products--
idProduct  PK
Category FK
Amount 
Name 

--Category--
idCategory PK
Category Name
```

if i have 20 products of different categories for example 3 cars 5 planes 9 types of food 
how do i get all of them in a new joined table like this

```
Category Name (from --Category--)  Amount of every product (from --Products--)
Cars                                   3 
Planes                                 9
```

And so on , i don't have a table with all the elements from each category so what should i do ?

Comment: Google -> `SQL Tutorial` or `SQL Joins` .

Comment: SELECT p.IdCategorie , c.Categorie 
FROM Produse
INNER JOIN Categorii 
ON Produse.IdCategorie = Categorii.IdCategorie , Produse AS p, Categorii AS c;

Comment: [edit] your question, don't post code in comments. Also which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may looking for simple join with aggregate function

```
SELECT CategoryName,COUNT(p.Category ) AS [Amount of every product ]
FROM Category c
INNER JOIN Product p ON c.idCategory = p.Category 
GROUP BY CategoryName
```

Comment: Yes , this is working , thank you . I need some examples untill i will be able to do it by myself .